# Can we configure logpath of mongodb to other machine path?

Tags: mongodb

I had configure the logpath of the mongodb to current machine desktop as shown following

```
logpath=./../root/Desktop/mongo/mongo1.log
```

It's working fine,but i wanted to store it to other machine.I tried with following

```
logpath=Username@IPaddress:~/Desktop/mongo/mongo1.log
```

But It's not working for me, so anybody knows how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea what you're thinking, writing logs always need a connection between servers, you can spend the daily file logs with [logRotate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/logRotate/) mongo command and then send the file log daily for the other server with Cron Job ...

Answer (score 0):

The `logpath` option only applies to file system paths.

If you want to log to a remote machine, one possibility (on Unix-ish systems) would be to use the [`syslog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption--syslog) option instead. The syslog daemon provides services for filtering and redirecting logs to remote syslog hosts.